# In a Linked List suppose we have a node "Current", does "Current=null" and ''Current.next=null" have the same meaning?

Tags: java, linked-list

```
while ( current != null ) {
  current=current.next;
}
```

and

```
while ( current.next != null ) {
  current=current.next;
}
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The last node's `next` will point to `null`. so after this line

```
current=current.next;
```

current will be `null` and if you use this condition

```
while(current.next!=null)
```

you'll get `NullPointerException`